# What software do I need to shift an image within its frame?

Tags: software-recommendation, alignment, free, images

I am trying to create a time-lapse sequence of my house demolition, but have not used specialised time-lapse equipment or software, just my compact digital camera on a fixed-point tripod in the garden.  Perhaps unsurprisingly, the images have ended up not quite as 'fixed' in reference to each other as I'd have liked.

Consequently I'm looking for something like the Picasa 'rotate' facility, which will allow me to shift each image freely within a set grid, and thus register each one around the same point. Freeware would be great.

Comment: Did you press the button every few sec or is it a video? Or is it just a collection of photos you want to put together?

Comment: Just a collection of photos, Sam.

Answer (score 1):

1 way is to use an online photo editor like pixlr http://apps.pixlr.com/editor/. You don't have to download or signup.

You can open the first image, file -> open image

If you want to re-size the image go to image -> image size (You will have to do this for all of them if you start resizing)

Open your second photo, file -> open image

Double click on the lock icon to unlock that image

[image: unlock the layer]

use the move tool (press V on the keyboard) to move the second image onto the first image canvas.

You can lower the opacity of the second picture by selecting the layer with the second image and lowering the opacity

[image: lower the opacity]

Use the move tool again (V) and move that second image around until the houses align. Once they look good put the second image layer opacity back to 100%.

Repeat this process with all images to place them over each other.

After that is all over you might need to crop the canvas using the crop tool (C).

**Saving**

Save with all images still there, file -> save

For the next image hide the top layer and again save

[image: hide layer]

repeat until all images are saved.

This is basically the same process you would do in most image editing programs. I am not aware of any automated programs for aligned images.

**Creating a gif from pictures**

If you want to make this into a gif there are plenty of online generators that will do this for you. Just Google "create gif online from pictures".

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, for sharing your knowledge.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: Yup!  Tried it and with a little persistence got what I needed.  Sincere thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop has a 30-day free trial period. It also has the ability to combine all the still photos into an animation once you stack them all.

Comment: Thanks Voxwoman! Will give it a try along with the other suggestion.